# Adding onclick event in JavaScript with parameters

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to make a dropdown to display the results of a request given what the user writes in a field.
The problem I'm encountering is that when I try to add an onclick event to each item in the dropdown, only the last one acts like expected.

The dropdown is a section and I try to include sections in it.
Here is the dropdown :

```
<section id="projectDrop">
</section>
```

Here is the code :

```
var j = 0;
var tmp;
for (var i=0;((i<infos.projects.length) && (i<5));i++)
{
    if (infos.projects[i].name.toLowerCase().match(projectName.value.toLowerCase()))
    {
        projectDrop.innerHTML += '<section id="project' + j + '">' + infos.projects[i].name + '</section>';
        tmp = document.getElementById('project' + j);
        projectDrop.style.height = (j+1)*20 + 'px';
        tmp.style.top = j*20 + 'px';
        tmp.style.height = '20 px'; 
        tmp.style.width = '100%';
        tmp.style.color = 'rgb(0, 0, 145)';
        tmp.style.textAlign = 'center';
        tmp.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        tmp.style.zIndex = 5;
        tmp.onclick = function(name, key)
        {
            return function()
            { 
                return insertProject(name, key);
            };
        } (infos.projects[i].name, infos.projects[i].key);
    ++j;
    }
}
```

The result is visually as I expected, I can see the dropdown with all my projects listed and a pointer while hovering etc...
But only the last project is clickable and trigger the "insertProject" function while the other do nothing.
If someone could help me solve that !

Comment: why onClick for each option

Comment: I don't know, I just figured out that it was the way to go.
Is there a way to set only one onClick for the dropdown ?

Comment: use .on('click', function(e) { <-- you can get what you need from e

Comment: one comment is you need to simplify your function

Comment: @PSR I don't use a select box, I tried to make a custom dropdown, should have precised it, the projectDrop is a section as well.
I'm gonna give a try to .on

Comment: `.on()` is jQuery so that won't work unless you have jQuery included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the key somewhere. Take a look at the solution below, I have used the `data-key` attribute on the `<section>` to store the key.

Also note how I have changed the code to create the element object and assign its properties, instead of building a raw string of HTML. The problem with building HTML as a string is you have to worry about escaping quotes, whereas this way you don't.

```
var j = 0;
var tmp;
for (var i=0;((i<infos.projects.length) && (i<5));i++)
{
    if (infos.projects[i].name.toLowerCase().match(projectName.value.toLowerCase()))
    {
        tmp = document.createElement('section');
        tmp.id = "project" + j;
        tmp.setAttribute('data-key', infos.projects[i].key);
        tmp.innerHTML = infos.projects[i].name;

        projectDrop.style.height = (j+1)*20 + 'px';
        tmp.style.top = j*20 + 'px';
        tmp.style.height = '20 px'; 
        tmp.style.width = '100%';
        tmp.style.color = 'rgb(0, 0, 145)';
        tmp.style.textAlign = 'center';
        tmp.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        tmp.style.zIndex = 5;
        tmp.onclick = function(){
            insertProject(this.innerHTML, this.getAttribute('data-key'));
        };

        projectDrop.appendChild(tmp);

        ++j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem and thanks a lot too to make me know about the createElement ! I was feeling that the innerHTML was quite wrong but didn't see any other way to do it.

Comment: @VivienFaure yes, the problem with building the HTML is if it contained a quote it would break, for example `<section key="some"thing">`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
        tmp.onclick = function(name, key)
        {
            return function()
            { 
                return insertProject(name, key);
            };
        } (infos.projects[i].name, infos.projects[i].key);
```

to

```
        tmp.onclick = function(j){
          return function(name, key)
          {
            return function()
            { 
                return insertProject(name, key);
            };
          } (infos.projects[j].name, infos.projects[j].key);
        }(i)
```